# How do i complete my codes to make this shape?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to make a shape using Python's "Turtle" library. I made a list named "Square" which contains some commands that prints a part of my shape which is a square. I am not too familiar with Python and even Python's Turtle Library and i do not know too much about it. By the way, i want to run the list named "Square" twice, but it only runs the list once. Any way to run it twice? What am i doing wrong? Maybe python cannot make a list with commands such as `forward()`, `left()`,`right()` and `backward()`?

```
from turtle import *

for i in range(8):
    forward(100)
    left(45)

turns = [(40, 40), (90, 40), (80, 40), (90, 40), (90, 50), (90, 40), (80, 40), (90, 40)]

forward(46)

for l_angle, r_angle in turns:
    left(l_angle)
    forward(50)
    right(r_angle)
    forward(50)

penup()
goto(0, 0)

left(40)
forward(46)
left(90)
forward(60)
pendown()
forward(115)

square = [right(50), forward(50), left(140), penup(), forward(75), left(140), forward(5), pendown(), forward(43), right(50)]

forward(120)

for i in range(2):
    for command in square:
        command
```

Comment: Please at least see my answer at the linked duplicate, especially the part titled "dealing with arguments". Also, going forward it will be useful for you to learn proper terminology. It is basically never correct to use the word "command" when talking about a modern programming language, aside from shell/batch scripting. What you are talking about here are **functions**. Also: you cannot "run" a list, and the reason the functions are only called once has **nothing to do with** the `for` loop - it's because you call them **before** putting **their results** in the list.